# Level function not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a table with a row group hierarchy and I would like to be able to control the indentation amount based on the group level.  There are other things I need to be able to do programmatically using this information as well.

The Level() function in SSRS seems straightforward.  From the IDE description:

> Returns a zero-based integer representing the current depth level of a recursive hierarchy.
>
> Example:
> =Level()
> =Level("GroupByInitial")

Unfortunately, the function always returns a value of zero.  I have used it in the group header column as well as in the data region, in various group levels, and I have tried passing the function the name of the top level group, to no avail.

I feel pretty sure I am using the function correctly, but I would appreciate any corrections or hints on how to use this, or any troubleshooting advice on how I could find out if there's something wrong with SSRS that it's not working as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEVEL() function is used for a hierarchy. You need to go to Advanced in Group property and specify the recursive parent to build a recursive hierarchy.
See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255243.aspx

Comment: Well, my groups _are_ hierarchical.  It's the "recursive" part that got me.  It seems strange that this function wouldn't work for a standard group hierarchy as well, though.